# RxJS: scan operator inside switchMap/mergeMap

Tags: typescript, rxjs

We're using the scan operator for our 'load more' button in our table. With the scan operator, we just accumulate the new results with the previous ones.
However, we encountered some unexpected-to-us behaviour.

To simplify, let's say we have the following code:

```js
const fakeRequest = of('response').pipe(delay(2000));
interval(1000).pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => fakeRequest),
    scan<string>((allResponses, currentResponse) => [...allResponses, currentResponse], []),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

produces:

```
["response"]
["response", "response"]
["response", "response", "response"]
["response", "response", "response", "response"]
...
```

While, if we just move the scan operator inside the mergeMap/switchMap operator:

```js
interval(1000).pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => fakeRequest.pipe(
        scan<string>((allResponses, currentResponse) => [...allResponses, currentResponse], []),
    )),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

We get the following results:

```
["response"]
["response"]
["response"]
["response"]
...
```

The scan operator isn't executed in the second example. I would expect the switchMap/mergeMap just flattens the inner observable, which has the scan operator piped into it.

- Is this desired behaviour?
- If so, can anyone explain why this is happening?
- If so, is there another way/workaround to achieve the same behavior inside the mergeMap or switchMap operators?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that scan() works on the emitted data and mergeMap does the job of subscribing to the inner observable before mapping the value to the outer observable. If you put the scan() operator in the fakeRequest declaration statement, it'll, perhaps, be more clear that the scan doesn't get any values because of().pipe(delay()) is never subscribed to emit 'response'.

Comment: your first example is working fine why you want to switch to second one

Comment: @FanCheung 1. because our fakeRequest observable comes from a service. We want to include the scan functionality in our data service because it belongs there. However, for some reason, we had to use a switchMap in our page component. Now we need to add the scan functionality in our component, which is not what we want and it is very unexpected behavior. We thought switchMap would almost literally 'switch' to the inner Observable, including the scan operator.
2. Just trying to get to learn the quirks. We didn't expect operators of an inner observable to just being 'ignored'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the difference is because in the first case:

```
interval(1000).pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => fakeRequest),
    scan<string>((allResponses, currentResponse) => [...allResponses, currentResponse], []),
)
```

You are `scan`ning the emissions from ALL observables created within `mergeMap`.

However, in the second case:

```
interval(1000).pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => fakeRequest.pipe(
        scan<string>((allResponses, currentResponse) => [...allResponses, currentResponse], []),
    )),
)
```

You are `scan`ning the emissions from an observable, that only emits once!

Essentially, `mergeMap()` is a source that emits multiple times.  The `fakeResponse` observable is a source that only emits once.

I saw from your comment your reason for wanting to move the `scan` under the response, was due to wanting to perform the `scan` in your service, so individual consumers don't need to.  I know this is an old question, so maybe you figured this out by now, but you can certainly do the scan logic in your service (as long as your interval() is also in there) by tacking on a `.pipe(scan(...))`.